# Perl, how to choose a directory

Tags: perl, if-statement, directory

I'm trying to determine which of the content of a folder is a directory and which is a file, I wrote the following but the result is not what I would expect:

```
opendir DH, $dir or die "Cannot open Dir: $!";
my @dirs = grep !/^\.\.?$/, readdir DH ;
foreach my $files (@dirs) {
    print $files."<br>";
    if ( -d $files ) 
    {
        print $files." is a directory<br>";
    }
}
closedir DH;
```

### The result is something as the example below:

```
.file1
file.log
file3.zip
file4
file5.zip
dir1.name1.suffix1.yyyy.MM.dd.hh.mm.ss
file5.zip
file6.tar
dir2
dir3.name1.suffix1.yyyy.MM.dd.hh.mm.ss
```

---

where the item starting with dir are actual directory, so my question is why the if is failing discover them as such?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Calling that variable `$files` has a really good chance of confusing someone (perhaps even you) in the future. Why not call it `$file`?

Comment: Nit: `/^\.\.?$/` filters out dot-newline and dot-dot-newline. `$` should be `\z`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$dir`is missing...

```
if ( -d "$dir/$files" )
    {
        print $files." is a directory<br>";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest to `chdir` to `$dir` so that you don't have to prefix the node names with the path. You can also `use autodie` if you are running Perl v5.10.1 or better. Finally, if you use `$_` as your loop control variable (the file/directory names) you can omit it from the parameters of `print`, `-d` and regex matches

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10.1;
use autodie;

my ($dir) = @ARGV;

opendir my $dh, $dir;
chdir $dh;

while ( readdir $dh ) {
    next if /\A\.\.?\z/;
    print;
    print " is a directory" if -d;
    print "<br/>\n";
}

... # local expires. working directory returns to its original value
```

---

#### Update

In view of [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami)'s (deleted) comment about returning back to the original working directory, here's an example of using the [`File::chdir`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::chdir) module to do this tidily. It exports a tied variable `$CWD` which will change your working directory if you assign to it. You can also localise it, so just wrapping the above code in braces and adding a new local value for `$CWD` keeps things neat. Note that `File::chdir` is not a core module so you will likely need to install it

**Note** however that there is still a very small possibility that the process may be started with a present working directory that it cannot `chdir` to. This module will not solve that problem

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10.1;
use autodie;

use File::chdir;

my ($dir) = @ARGV;

{
    opendir my $dh, $dir;
    local $CWD = $dir;

    while ( readdir $dh ) {
        next if /\A\.\.?\z/;
        print;
        print " is a directory" if -d;
        print "<br/>\n";
    }
}
```